# html background without css

Tags: html, background

I want to make a menu for a restaurant without using css. I made the background with PS but all I can find is how to put it in the body and on top of that I can't make it no-repeat. A friend told me I can do it using tables but I can't find anything about background on tables without css either.
How can I make an element with a "background" or an  and put some text (and other images) on top of it without using css?

Comment: css doesn't appreciate your hate

Comment: are you not wanting to use css because it repeated on your first attempts? `background-size: cover` sounds like it'd meet your desires

Comment: There is absolutely no hate against css. I am said I must do it without using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert background="myback.gif" into the TABLE tag...

```
<table  background="myback.gif">
<tr>
  <td width="50" align="center">4</td>
  <td width="50" align="center">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The following link may be useful:

http://www.htmliseasy.com/table_tutor/background.html